# Is it always important to include the 'why' in your question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I always include some background info in questions I ask. I've seen many questions on here where that hasn't been done, and I see comments along the lines of:

> 'Why are you trying to do his? Perhaps if you posted some details
>   about the problem you are attempting to solve, then the Community
>   could find a workaround for you'

Seems reasonable enough. I ask questions on here because I'm not an expert - I can't think of every possible approach to answering the question, at least not at this level of expertise. So providing background can help everyone else think laterally on the question and potentially discover a work-around that achieves the same end, only via a different route than the OP had envisaged.

However I'm beginning to question that thought. On a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958370/how-to-hide-macro-code-from-a-user-using-vba) I was asking for something very specific but included the situation, which resulted in a whole train of comments regarding the situation, and replies by me explaining it in more detail. But none of that helped to answer the question itself. I feel the whole situation would've been much clearer if I'd just left out the background info.

So what I want to know is: is a question of the form 'How do I do ...' with no explanation of why you want to do that acceptable?

- On the one hand, SO is a database of knowledge, sometimes a simple 'No that's not possible for these reasons...' would suffice as an answer.
- On the other hand, perhaps background is necessary to open up other avenues, or simply provide more key-words for a site search to draw on (what's the point of a database if you can't find anything on it because the questions are *too* concise).

And can you ever be sure that your question is niche enough that you've come up with the only possible approach to solving it and you just need to know if it's feasible or not?

In my example I think I did, but how can I be sure before posting?

#### Update RE. Possible duplicate

I think this question, certainly in taking the perspective of the OP providing info (as opposed to the Answerers requesting it), is slightly nuanced and different from the proposed duplicate. Those questions address the obvious need for context in so called XY problems, I'm really interested in when you can avoid that. Specifically

- Is it right to omit context in order to streamline a question-answer process; to avoid people asking for expansion of irrelevant context when none is needed

  - If so, how do you determine when you have a question that doesn't require context
- And is it useful to have such narrow solution-based questions that, if an implementation of that solution does not exist, instead of exploring other paths, the question is answered as 'No, that's not possible because...'

  - The justification for that sort of question being that it clearly guides users on SO away from that line of questioning, whereas a convoluted `Y` to `X` and back to `Y` question would be much more difficult to follow.

I'm not satisfied with the answers to the proposed duplicates as I don't think they address these nuances.

Comment: It might be that we try to detect if you have an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @rene It may be that, it may however be *seen* as an x-y problem (when it isn't really) - i.e. other users try to glean `X` from OP's `Y`, thinking it will be necessary, but instead fog up the question. Indeed `Y` may be the correct route, and the user only requires implementation to find a solution. In fact, if it's the case that `Y` is the most obvious approach to tackling the problem, then I'd argue you *shouldn't* offer context, as this will make the question less clear to other users searching SO. Objectively deciding what the most obvious approach is, would be tricky.

Comment: IMO it's fine to leave a question unsolved (yet answered) to notify future users of a false path. So offering up a solution as the question seems acceptable to me, as long as the solution reasoning is clear and obvious. Giving the context and clouding up the question with comments, only to come in a full circle and be told that the approach to solving `X` would indeed be the `Y` that you first proposed seems like something to avoid.

Comment: @gnat Hmmm, I'm not convinced. Certainly the question isn't a duplicate - this one focuses on Questioners posting content, that one on Answerers requesting it - slight difference. As for the answer, well I agree it addresses the need for context in questions where that context restricts the possible solutions, but I still think there's discussion to be had over possible drawbacks - especially in questions where the restriction is implicit based on the solution proposed in the question. Sure that restriction may be made more clear by the process of working through the context, but not always.

Comment: @Greedo "it may however be *seen* as an XY problem (when it isn't really)" What authority are you appealing to in order to declare that a problem seen by the community as being an XY problem really isn't an XY probem? The one authority that OPs always have at hand is their own authority. Are you suggesting that whenever an OP declares that their question is not an XY problem then their declaration overrides the view of the community? Otherwise, what authority should have the power to override the community's view that a question presents an XY problem?

Comment: @Louis Perhaps I am misunderstanding the term. I see an 'XY' problem as one where solution Y is the question, as opposed to a problem X *for which other solutions exist*. What I'm talking about is a problem X for which the proposed solution Y is the *only* possible solution, as in my specific example (I can explain why I cite that if need be). So although the problem appears to be XY, it *objectively* isn't **based on the criteria I have imposed on the definition: namely that a problem is XY if finding X will present more possible solutions than starting from Y alone** My meaning, maybe misuse

Comment: For that specific question, I think your comments were just clearer than the original question about what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't think of every possible approach to answering the question

Actually, you can't be expected to know the *best* approach dealing with a issue. Normally, questions on the site are being asked because the asker has a problem with his solution and can't figure out that maybe the solution is their problem, that there are better ways to deal with the issue, or that their solution introduce other problems.

Including the task you are trying to complete along with the solution you could think of, allows the question to be able to have either response:

1. The problem is that you didn't approached correctly the issue, other point of view was needed.
2. Your approach was good and you only need help implementing it.

In any case, you get the best of all scenarios.